# Align vertically font awesome icon with input submit inside a span tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

My icon is not centered to my input button, how do I get them aligned?

```
<span>
<i class="far fa-heart my-auto"></i>
<input type="submit" class="btn favorite-button bold-font py-0 px-1" name="favorite" value="Add to Favorites">
</span>
```

The icon does not have margin or padding so I cannot simply do a bootstrap "my-auto"

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: What font-size is this? `<input type="submit" class="btn favorite-button bold-font py-0 px-1" name="favorite" value="Add to Favorites">` Just set the font-size of `<i class="far fa-heart my-auto"></i>` to the same?

Comment: What is the *desired* alignment in your example? The alignment in your image appears baseline, though it appears as though the `font-size` is slightly largely for the image? Just set them to be the same.

Comment: try matching font-size and line height

Comment: line-height adjusts both, it just moves the entire span tag, icon is still not centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap 4.0 flex class to align item in the center

```css
i {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<span class="d-flex align-items-center mt-2 ml-2">
                <i class="far fa-heart my-auto"></i>
                <input type="submit" class="btn favorite-button font-weight-bold py-0 px-1" name="favorite" value="Add to Favorites">
              </div>
```

Comment: thanks for this fix, didn realise i only needed d-flex

Answer (score 1):

From the title i guess what you should try is to change the display to flex column and align the contents

```
<span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 150px;">
        <i class="far fa-heart my-auto"></i>
        <input type="submit" class="btn favorite-button bold-font py-0 px-1" name="favorite" value="Add to Favorites">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your "`far`" class as below;

```
.far {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```